Delete [bottom] and [bracket]
Obviously someone overlooked that we have a "bottom-bracket" tag and tagged their questions with the tags "bottom" and "bracket". I have already corrected those occasions to point to "bottom-bracket" but "bottom" and "bracket" still show up in the tags recommendation list of you want to add tags and start typing "Bo" or "bra".
I think we should delete "bottom" and "bracket" to prevent confusion for future users.

Tags without existing questions will automatically be deleted by the system daily.

Well then... Thanks for the clarification.

Are there situations where the tag bottom or the tag bracket are right but not the combined tag?

I cannot really imagine such with respect to cycling... Those that I could appear somewhat forcefully constructed. @Willeke

If you see such unwanted tags being used please re-tag or flag for moderator attention so a mod can de the edit.
As users above a certain rep can create tags they might reappear even when gotten rid of before.
But tags without questions do disappear.
